# Compare a cell to a range of cells in a workbook and set the result as another range of cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 sheets

- Sheet1
- Sheet2

In Sheet 1 I have these cells:

```
A
Critical 
Critical 
Minor 
Medium
```

In Sheet 2 I have this table:

```
A       B
Urgent  Critical
High    Major
Medium  Medium
Low     Minor
```

How can I map Sheet1's column A to Sheet2's column B and set the convert Sheet1's column A to Sheet2's column A?

This is what I have so far but it only shows the #VALUE error

```
=INDEX(A1:$,MATCH('Sheet2'!B1:B4,0),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MATCH(A1,Sheet2!B:B,0))
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll accept this answer when the limit is up.